# .htaccess rule redirecting, but not rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a simple rewrite rule.
I want all trafic going to a given path to get contetns from another

I have these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#this is the rule I am implementing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ "/foo/bar/" [L]

#This rule is working
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ "/foo/bar/index.php?fb=$1&%1 [L]
```

There is one rule more after this one and it's working:

Like before it does not work. Like this, it does:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ "/foo/bar/" [R,L]
```

I want to rewrite, not redirect, but I often use the R just to test.
I am probably doing something wrong, but what?

Note: I had another rule before, for rewrite, that worked. Its not missing any modules (I think).

Comment: Do you have other rules?

Comment: @JonLin, yes I will post them

Comment: @anubhava no, just plain html and  a simple php script

Comment: Well, if I have [R] so, redirect, it redicts. If I really want a rewrite nothing happens. I just ge thte default page / and not /foo/bar/

Comment: What URL are you using to test this? Where is this htaccess located?

Comment: Sorry, I cant reveal the full url. This is still an ongoing project and its a development environment.

Comment: And you expect someone to help you without providing required information?

Comment: @anubhava I don't understand your comment. I understand if you can't help but maybe someone experienced something similar. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After some fighting I discovered the problem.

For this rule to work:

```
#this is the rule I am implementing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ "/foo/bar/" [L]
```

It needs to be written like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/index.php$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ "/foo/bar/" [L]
```

It needed the index.php. You should replace for the file or resource that you have.